# Is there an o(1) way to convert the primitive int[] to the wrapper class Integer[]?

Tags: java

I've seen a variety of solutions to this problem:

```
public static Integer[] toConvertInteger(int[] ids) {

  Integer[] newArray = new Integer[ids.length];
     for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
       newArray[i] = Integer.valueOf(ids[i]);
     }
   return newArray;
}
```

and

```
int[] data = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

// To boxed array
Integer[] what = Arrays.stream( data ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );
Integer[] ever = IntStream.of( data ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );

// To boxed list
List<Integer> you  = Arrays.stream( data ).boxed().collect( Collectors.toList() );
List<Integer> like = IntStream.of( data ).boxed().collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

However, both solutions just seem so complex. Maybe they are outdated solutions. Is there any way to solve this problem in o(1) or in a more readable / clean solution.

Context of my usage:

```
Set<Integer> mySet = new Set<Integer>(int[] array..);
```

Comment: No, and there can't be.

Comment: No, it must be O(n), even you use any built-in function or library function.